# Multivalue type settings bundle fields alway return null

Tags: iphone, web-applications, settings.bundle

I have a problem retrieving default values from the settings bundle when first launching an App. All non-multivalue fields return the default correctly. All multivalue fields return NULL. The code I am using to retrieve the current value:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *upt=[defaults objectForKey:@"upthreshold"];
```

The relevant section from Root.plist is:

```
                <dict>
                    <key>Title</key>
                    <string>Update Threshold</string>
                    <key>Type</key>
                    <string>PSMultiValueSpecifier</string>
                    <key>Key</key>
                    <string>upthreshold</string>
                    <key>DefaultValue</key>
                    <string>15</string>
                    <key>Titles</key>
                    <array>
                            <string>2 km</string>
                            <string>5 km</string>
                            <string>10 km</string>
                            <string>15 km</string>
                            <string>25 km</string>
                            <string>50 km</string>
                            <string>75 km</string>
                            <string>100 km</string>
                            <string>150 km</string>
                            <string>250 km</string>
                            <string>500 km</string>
                            <string>1000 km</string>
                    </array>
                    <key>Values</key>
                    <array>
                            <string>2</string>
                            <string>5</string>
                            <string>10</string>
                            <string>15</string>
                            <string>25</string>
                            <string>50</string>
                            <string>75</string>
                            <string>100</string>
                            <string>150</string>
                            <string>250</string>
                            <string>500</string>
                            <string>1000</string>
                    </array>
            </dict>
```

I would expect that "15" would come back as the current value as it is set to the default value. Is there some different processing required for Multivalue fields? As I said previously, there are 6 fields prior to this that return their values correctly. This field and the following 2 Multivalue fields do not. The multivalue fields are all defined the same.

Comment: I could be misunderstanding this, but it looks like "upthreshold" is a value for the key "Key", not a key itself.

Comment: I have all the fields setup this way and every example I've seen sets the "Key" this way and that is the way you refer to the field when you do a objectForKey call. I think this is right. If not, how would you define it?

Comment: I've always had trouble with default values if the settings page hasn't been visited yet. I tend to detect nil and hardcode a default into the app. It's not pretty but it works :(

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If the value wasn't changed by the user in the settings app there is no setting.
The default value specified in the settings bundle is only the default for display in the settings app

you have to manually register your default values. NSUserdefaults doesn't use the defaults from the settings bundle.
Use something like this, add it at the beginning of your app (before you access the userdefaults).
Registered Userdefaults are not saved to disk or anything. You have to register them every time you start the app.

```
NSDictionary *userDefaultsDefaults = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                      @"15", @"upthreshold",
                                      nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:userDefaultsDefaults];
```

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick. It seems odd that the defaults worked for the single value fields before the change (I never set them using the settings app). It seems counter-intuitive to have a default value that is not really one without having to set it everytime in the app. Kind of takes away from a feature that reduces programming time. Regardless, thanks for the help.

Comment: This misfeature is not related to value type -- I'm having the same problem with Booleans (the specified default is YES, but [defaults boolForKey:...] returns NO).

Comment: I just run into this problem. If you do `registerDefaults` for just one key, how is it different to simply set the object for the given key?

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this problem and I ask myself why the settings bundle provides a default value, if this value can never be read from the `NSUserDefaults`.

I created a swift extension that does the following:

- Read the value for a given key
- If the key does not exist set a default and return this default

So I can do this:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().settignsStringValue("MYPREFS_DOMAIN", defaultValue: "domain.com")
```

This is the extension:

```
extension NSUserDefaults{

    func settingsBoolValue(key: String, defaultValue: Bool) -> Bool{
        // The case for Bool is different as it would return `false` when the key is not set.
        if let v: AnyObject = self.objectForKey(key){
            // The boolean value exists
        } else {
            self.setObject(defaultValue, forKey: key)
        }

        return self.boolForKey(key)
    }

    func settingsStringValue(key: String, defaultValue: String) -> String{
        if let v = self.stringForKey(key){
            return v
        } else {
            self.setObject(defaultValue, forKey: key)
            return defaultValue
        }
    }
}
```