# NSUserDefaults default value returning (null)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

This is probably something really simple that I am missing, why when using the code below to access settings does the default value return as `(null)`

```
- (void)updateUIForDistanceUnits {
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *test = [userDefaults stringForKey:@"IDDistance"];
    NSLog(@"DISTANCE: %@", test);
}
```

Root.plist

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multivalue type settings bundle fields alway return null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784171/multivalue-type-settings-bundle-fields-alway-return-null)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default value in `Root.plist` is just what the UI shows if there's no value set, and you have to do the same in your code or set up `[NSUserDefaults -registerDefaults]` correctly in your application.

You should find that once you set the value in Settings.app `NSUserDefaults` will return the correct value.