# how to retrieve user setting in iOS? [Xcode 7 + Swift 2]

Tags: swift2, ios9, xcode7, settings.bundle, root.plist

I am using **Xcode 7** + **Swift 2**.

I added a `setting.bundle` to the root of my app with a single text field.

**Root.plist** looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>StringsTable</key>
    <string>Root</string>
    <key>PreferenceSpecifiers</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Type</key>
            <string>PSGroupSpecifier</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>Controller Settings:</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Type</key>
            <string>PSTextFieldSpecifier</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>Enter Text</string>
            <key>Key</key>
            <string>key</string>
            <key>DefaultValue</key>
            <string>Text</string>
            <key>IsSecure</key>
            <false/>
            <key>KeyboardType</key>
            <string>NumbersAndPunctuation</string>
            <key>AutocapitalizationType</key>
            <string>None</string>
            <key>AutocorrectionType</key>
            <string>No</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I then try to:

1. Read the default value ("Text")
2. Change the text field in the iOS settings and then read the new `String`.

I used this two lines of code:

```
let settings = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
let setting_value = settings.stringForKey("key")! as String
```

but all i get is this error and the app would not continue:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

all I want is to read the setting and display the `String` to a label.

Thanks.

EDIT:
I Understand now that the error is because the value in not assigned yet.
to prevent the error I put 'if' before:

```
if let name = settings.stringForKey("key") {
     print(name)
   }
```

but how can I actually read the value inside "key"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSUserDefaults default value returning (null)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706685/nsuserdefaults-default-value-returning-null)

Comment: You need to use `NSUserDefaults.registerDefaults()` to set up the "default defaults" in your application. The `root.plist` in the settings bundle only affects what happens in the Settings app. [Here's another example.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784171/multivalue-type-settings-bundle-fields-alway-return-null)

Comment: so if understand correctly `NSUserDefaults.registerDefaults()` is for defaults values and `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()` are for user entered settings?

Comment: Not exactly. You use `registerDefaults` to specify the "default values" that will be seen in `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults` if no value was ever set. You always use `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults` to read values in your app.

Comment: OK I believe this answer my question. I am not fully understand this but I will try to read about this in the Swift documentation.