# Settings bundle not syncing up with NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, settings.bundle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multivalue type settings bundle fields alway return null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784171/multivalue-type-settings-bundle-fields-alway-return-null)

I have a settings bundle in my iOS app which generates the following table in the settings  [app](http://tinypic.com/r/j0zbbt/6)

In my app I attempt to generate the same table using NSUserDefaults and end up with [this](http://tinypic.com/r/1gi3ys/6)

My code to retrieve the values goes is:

```
NSUserDefaults* userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
ds->use_cache = [userDefaults boolForKey:@"use_cache"];
ds->high_bitrate = [userDefaults boolForKey:@"high_bitrate"];
```

and

```
NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[[cell detailTextLabel] setText:[defaults stringForKey:@"version"]];
```

The stringForKey with the key "version" always returns a null value. I can't seem to get my app to recognise the default parameters I have defined in the settings bundle.

Here is my settings [bundle](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2hyjpj&s=6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default values for the settings should be set using the `registerDefaults:` method. This sets up an `NSRegistrationDomain` from which they will be available. An example for this is below. Thanks to jrturton & Matthias Bauch for pointing out the problem with my first answer that was previously referring to http://greghaygood.com/2009/03/09/updating-nsuserdefaults-from-settingsbundle.

```
NSDictionary *appDefaults = [ NSDictionary
                              dictionaryWithObject:@"default_version_value" forKey:@"version" ];

[ [ NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults ] registerDefaults:appDefaults ];

NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [ NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults ];
```

Also note these default values need to be set every time the application starts as stated in the documentation for `registerDefaults:`.

> The contents of the registration domain are not written to disk; you need to call this method each time your application starts. You can place a plist file in the application's Resources directory and call registerDefaults: with the contents that you read in from that file.

Comment: Isn't that just a long and tedious manual version of `registerDefaults:`, which is the actual answer?

Comment: It's even worse then [`registerDefaults:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000318-CIHDDCDB), because it actually persists those default values. If you want to change the default value in the next version of the app you can't figure out if the user choose to use the default value or if the default value was just used because the user never changed it.

Comment: I've discovered this: http://ijure.org/wp/archives/179
I can't believe iOS doesn't load the defaults into the NSUserDefaults by default... isn't this a bug?

Comment: Thanks for sharing that link. It does seem that default values should perhaps be set automatically. However, the settings bundle is serving more as a data container, a list of properties, rather than determining any implicit behaviors.